# Date not localised

Tags: 17.04, indicator, time, date

I'm having an issue with date format. It shows as *short day, month, day number, time*. But all my location settings are GB, so I was expecting *short day, day number, month, time*.

I've tried updating it using `dconf` but even after restarting nothing changes even if I enter junk.

**Clarification:** I'm talking about the time/date indicator in the system panel.

`date` output:

```
Sat 7 Oct 08:44:55 BST 2017
```

`locale` output:

```
LANG=en_GB.UTF-8 
LANGUAGE=en_GB:en 
LC_CTYPE="en_GB.UTF-8" 
LC_NUMERIC=en_GB.UTF-8 
LC_TIME=en_GB.UTF-8 
LC_COLLATE="en_GB.UTF-8" 
LC_MONETARY=en_GB.UTF-8 
LC_MESSAGES="en_GB.UTF-8" 
LC_PAPER=en_GB.UTF-8 
LC_NAME=en_GB.UTF-8 
LC_ADDRESS=en_GB.UTF-8 
LC_TELEPHONE=en_GB.UTF-8 
LC_MEASUREMENT=en_GB.UTF-8 
LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_GB.UTF-8 
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: Can you please add the outputs of `date` and `locale` to your question?

Comment: That looks fine to me. All locale settings are en_GB and the date output is in the format `short weekday, day, short month, time, year`, which should be what you want. Where exactly is your problem?

Comment: it doesn't show like that in the toolbar:) , it shows as Sun Oct 8   21:26